# Scrolling list similar to setting hour list in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone

I would like to use component which looks like this list which you can use when setting hour in windows phone. What is this component name? How to add elements to it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its component in the Silverlight Toolkit is the LoopingSelector which enables users to implement various looping scenarios in an easy way. You can check that [link](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-LoopingSelector-in-depth--Part1-Visual-structure-and-API) for more info.